# MS Access Sequential number Calculation and record generation

Tags: ms-access

Ok, this one is new to me...  I have a table where the user enters the number of records to be entered (X).  I would like MS Access to calculate the number X down to and including 0, and enter those numbers as records in another table.

[User Entry Table].[Number] = 10

The following numbers are then added to table Y in Field Record Number

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

Comment: Each number would be assigned to a new row

Comment: Use VBA with looping structure. Develop code and if you encounter issue post question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Insert(nBase As Integer)
    Dim nIndex As Integer
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For nIndex = nBase To 0 Step -1
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO [User Entry Table] ([Number]) VALUES (" & nIndex & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to select best answer :)